# GraalVM - can you jar multiple languages together?

Tags: graalvm

I've read a bit about GraalVM on how to run node.js and Polygloting, but there's something I still haven't understood;

Can I `jar` a polyglot program, `java` + `node.js` (say SvelteKit server)?

Will GraalVM deal with packaging the full node code?

Comment: [here](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/embed-languages/#compile-and-run-a-polyglot-application) you can see js and java together but I never seen any project which uses this approach.

Comment: Thanks @ozkanpakdil. There's also some info on how to [run node.js on GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/js/NodeJS/) but, like you say, haven't also seen it used.